# svn: how to compare working copy of a branch, with a specific revision of the trunk

Tags: svn

This is a very common situation, and I cannot find in svn documentation or google-fu, a solution for it.

Suppose I copy a branch from a "known good" revision of the trunk and I check it out:

```
>svn copy -m 'my branch' -r 100 svn+ssh://svn/trunk svn+ssh://svn/my_branch
>svn co svn+ssh://svn/my_branch
>cd my_branch
```

Now I do many edits for files under `my_branch` directory, and periodically I merge with "known good" revisions of the trunk, like this:

```
>svn merge -r 100:110 svn+ssh://svn/trunk
```

At any point in time, I and my reviewer, want to see, all the differences for all the files under `my_branch` directory, compared to the last revision of the trunk I merged with (these are my edits + possibly changes resulting from conflicted merges). So, all the differences between all the files in the working copy, compared to the corresponding files in revision 110 of `svn+ssh://svn/trunk`.

How to do this?

Edit:  uzsolt suggested this:

```
svn diff ^/trunk@REV1 ^/my_branch@REV2
```

This is a good start, but I already had done something like this, and there are two problems with this suggestion:

1.It prints my changes, plus a gazillion of:

```
Property changes on: path/to/foobar
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mergeinfo
    Merged trunk:r90-110
```

I don't want those.

2.I don't want to commit my changes, and then compare that revision to a revision of the trunk. I want to compare the working copy, with a revision of the trunk.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin, a local guru where I work, gave the following answer:

```
svn diff --old ^/trunk@110 --new .
```

You still have to get rid of all the `Property changes on:` stuff.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks `--ignore-properties` is the option to suppress the properties? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.ignore_properties

Comment: @Yeti probably. Unfortunately I have svn version 1.6 where it was not yet available, so I did not know about it.

Comment: Ah, I see. :-) Any chances to upgrade to a more recent version?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood you but maybe the following helps you:

```
svn diff ^/trunk ^/my_branch
```

You can append revision number if you need:

```
svn diff ^/trunk@REV1 ^/my_branch@REV2
```

Comment: I asked for differences between working copy and a specific revision of the trunk. And what do you mean by `branches` ?  I don't have that in my path.

Comment: @MarkGaleck sorry, `branches` deleted (it's only a habit). Check my edits.

Comment: thank you, I will post an edit at the bottom in response to your answer, it is now printing something, but not what I wanted.

Comment: If you don't use `@REV2` in `^/my_branch` it will show diffs between trunk and current (uncommitted) `my_branch` - see the first suggestion.

Comment: no... it seems to then look at the latest _committed_ version

Comment: Sorry, you've right. As @MarkGaleck wrote you should change to `my_branch` and `svn diff ^/trunk/ .` (replace `^/my_branch` to `.`).